# Put lazy-loaded component in parent when route is active

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular5

I have a header with a space for components depending on what route is currently active.
If I am in the "shop" the component will be a shopping cart, if I am in the profile-section the component could be a notification hub.
But if I just place the component "shopping cart" in the header, the module "shop" always gets loaded, even if I am in the profile-section.

I want to place a component of a lazy loaded module dynamically in the parent module. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally found a solution. Actually not that hard:

Using [auxiliary Routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#componentless-routes):

i can now configure in my module shop:

```js
{path: '', component: ShoppingCartOverviewComponent, outlet: 'headerToolbar'}
```

and in my header:

```html
<router-outlet name="headerToolbar" ></router-outlet>
```

so i can dynamically place a component of a lazy loaded module dynamically in the parent.